# Wagtail: Unwanted wagtail queries on every page

Tags: django, performance, wagtail

I use Wagtail 5.2 and have on everypage this three queries.
[image]

Why is Wagtail doing this?

Even if I go to [www.example.com/admin/](http://www.example.com/admin/) (Default Django admin page) I can see this three queries?

1. Is this the default behavior or I am doing something wrong?
2. Is it possible to cache at least the first query somehow? I guess wagtail is trying to get for each the current site objects.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior - assuming you mean the Wagtail admin rather than the Django admin.

The first figures out what site you are on. You may only have one site configured but Wagtail inherently supports multiple sites. The next 2 are probably for building the page explorer in the most efficient way possible. If your database is anywhere close to tuned, that data will probably be in memory in the db so I wouldn't worry too much about these queries.

One thing I did learn the hard way, use the Title field in your page models for the title in your front end navigation. That will allow building your nav to be a single query to the wagtailcore_page table. If the navigation title and the title displayed on the page have to be different, make the one displayed on the page be the custom field.

Comment: "assuming you mean the Wagtail admin rather than the Django admin." => No I mean Django admin.

" If your database is anywhere close to tuned" How do you tune the database? Using indexes or what else can I do?

Comment: /admin is wagtail's admin page, /django-admin is the django admin page

Comment: Since those 3 queries are very common (for example are used to build the page explorer on all pages of the Wagtail admin), they should be in your database's memory - unless you have the database memory so constrained that the data needs to be paged out to make room for other information. And yes indexes are the usual database tuning technique but Wagtail will have created appropriate indices for the tables referenced in those queries.